# Orderby and thenby using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have below table for categories.

**tbCategories**

```
CatgID        CatgName
------        --------
  1           Catg1
  2           Catg2
  3           Catg3
  4           Catg4
```

Now I have items table which is categorized linking to above categories

**tbItem**

```
ItemID            ItemName           ItemCatg         Priority
------            --------           --------         --------
  1                Name 1               1                 1
  2                Name 2               1                 2
  3                Name 3               2                 1
  4                Name 4               3                 3
  5                Name 5               4                 2
  6                Name 6               3                 1
```

**Priority**

```
1 - High
2 - Medium
3 - Low
```

Now when I display the item data, I want the to first display items with category **`Catg1`**, **`Catg2`** and **`Catg4`** based on their priority, then display items with **`Catg3`** based on their priority.

I had tried below `LINQ` expression, but I did not succeed with that. My knowledge on `LINQ` or `SQL` is not too strong but that's how much I could reach.

```
model.items = db.tbItem.OrderBy(p=>p.ItemCatg).ThenBy(p=>p.Priority).ToList();
```

Could someone please show me the right way to achieve this functionality?

**UPDATE**

I would like to achieve below combination while displaying.

```
ItemID            ItemName           ItemCatg         Priority
------            --------           --------         --------
  1                Name 1               1                 1
  3                Name 3               2                 1
  2                Name 2               1                 2
  5                Name 5               4                 2
  6                Name 6               3                 1
  4                Name 4               3                 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a trick I've used in the past.  You're basically relying on the result of the comparison ordering things first by the non-3 categories (i.e., the false equates to 0, the true to 1) then by the priority, then by the category.

```
tbItems.OrderBy(p=>p.ItemCatg == 3).ThenBy(p=>p.Priority).ThenBy(p=>p.ItemCatg).ToList();
```

Here's a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2uesgN) example.

Here's the output from the example:

```
ItemID: 1    ItemName: Name 1    ItemCatg: 1    Priority: 1
ItemID: 3    ItemName: Name 3    ItemCatg: 2    Priority: 1
ItemID: 2    ItemName: Name 2    ItemCatg: 1    Priority: 2
ItemID: 5    ItemName: Name 5    ItemCatg: 4    Priority: 2
ItemID: 6    ItemName: Name 6    ItemCatg: 3    Priority: 1
ItemID: 4    ItemName: Name 4    ItemCatg: 3    Priority: 3
```

Comment: This seems good but once the item has been sorted items with catg1, catg2 and catg4 has to be displayed based on their priority.. Can you please imply that changes..??

Comment: The provided code does just that.  Have you looked at the example?  It should demonstrate the sorting as I understand you to be asking for it so perhaps I'm not getting exactly what you're after.

Comment: He's just asking for it to be sorted by priority before sorting by category (except for Cat 3 items, which should be at the bottom)

Comment: I attempted to make an edit to the existing answer instead of submitting my own, but basically swap places for `p=>p.ItemCatg` with `p=>p.Priority` and it'll work.

Comment: Got it now - I updated the fiddle itself and the output here to reflect this change.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Kcoder for clarifying, I read the OP too literally :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2:**

You can use multiple queries like this:

```
var query1 = model.items.Where(x => x.ItemCatg != 3).OrderBy(y => y.Priority);
var query2 = model.items.Where(x => x.ItemCatg == 3).OrderBy(y => y.Priority);
var query = query1.Concat(query2);
```

**Edit:**

If you want to group your item based on certain criteria, you probably could do something like this with LINQ:

```
model.items = db.tbItem.GroupBy(p=>p.ItemCatg)
   .OrderBy(p=>p.Priority).ToList();
```

This will give you groups based on `ItemCatg` and among that group, you order it by `Priority`.

**Original:**

Since your query is quite customized, you may consider to create a "mapping" between your actual column `ItemCatg` value in `tbItem` with the priority you want to assign:

```
ItemCatg -> Actual priority
1 -> 0
2 -> 1
4 -> 2 //here is the trick
3 -> 3
```

In that case, you could create list for mapping like this:

```
List<int> prioMap = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4, 3 };
```

And then use it like this:

```
model.items = db.tbItem.OrderBy(p=>prioMap.IndexOf(p.ItemCatg))
   .ThenBy(p=>p.Priority).ToList();
```

Main trick: `IndexOf` will give you the `index` of the item (`ItemCatg`) in the list.

Comment: No I think you got me wrong.. Priorities are for item not for categories.. But while displaying the item I first need to get items based on categories and then sort them based on their priority..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I see, seems like you are looking for `GroupBy`, is it?

Comment: Oh yea.. That might be right direction.. Could you please provide a solution with that?

Comment: Among that group how can I consider only 3 groups to order by their priority?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao if you need only those three groups, then it would have been easier because you only need to do `Where`, but if you want to combine it with the other one, then you need to use `.Union` which is more complicated I believe...

Comment: Ian.. I've updated my question with the desired result.. Could you please look into it and let me know if you can help on that?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao OK, give me a while, I'll try that fist. Because this I can no longer "imagine" - a bit more complex

Comment: Ian.. I think I got the answer.. :) Thanks for your time.. :) But yea.. Somehow `GroupBy` or `Union` as you said should help here too..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao OK, great! :) my solution would be to use multiple query and then concat to avoid complex single query. But glad that you got your answer already.:)