# How to aggregate order by's in c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, aggregate

So I have a function like below which takes in a list of objects and keeps including them into my query string. This works great.

```
query = includeExpressions.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
```

But what I am wanting to do is to Aggregate the OrderBys as well. This is where I am running into issues. The issue I have is that one must use **OrderBy** then use **ThenBy** on the same line. I've tried using a for loop first item use order by then on use thenby. The issue I am running in is that in order for thenby to be activated the order by needs to proceed it on the same object line.

```
query.OrderBy(orderBy).ThenBy
```

I can not do

```
var usedOrderBy = true;
        foreach (var orderBy in orderBys)
        {
            if (usedOrderBy)
            {
                query = query.OrderBy(orderBy);

                usedOrderBy = true;
            }
            else
            {
                query = query.ThenBy(orderBy); // <-- Can not locate thenby
            }
        }

any ides.
```

I want to pass in like

```
orderItems(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2)
```

Comment: Maybe this will help [Orderby and thenby using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728983/orderby-and-thenby-using-linq)

Comment: Remove the `usedOrderBy` and instead have a variable storing the results of the `OrderBy` (I am not sure of the type OTTOMH - probably `IOrderedQueryable`). Then inside the loop, check whether the `variable` is `null` or not (rather than checking the `bool`.

Comment: You can visit the expression tree to see if it contains an "OrderBy" method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
   var orderByList = new List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>();
            Expression<Func<TEntity,object>> orderBy1 = x => x.Id;
            Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderBy2 = x => x.ToString();
            Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderBy3 = x => x.Id;
            orderByList.Add(orderBy1);
            orderByList.Add(orderBy2);
            orderByList.Add(orderBy3);

            var resultOrderedQueryable = orderByList.Aggregate<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>(null, (current, orderBy) => current != null ? current.ThenBy(orderBy) : query.OrderBy(orderBy));
```

Comment: Didn't think of this, this works, I adjusted the answer to include orderby for thenby thx.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the type of `query` variable. [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby) is the extension method that can be applied to `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>` or `System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<TSource>` so you can't do just

```
IEnumerable<Point> points = GetPoints();
points = points.OrderBy(p => p.X);
points = points.ThenBy(p => p.Y);
```

You should have an extra variable for preordered result to solve your scenario like in an example below:

```
IEnumerable<Point> points = GetPoints();
var orderedPoints = points.OrderBy(p => p.X);
orderedPoints = orderedPoints.ThenBy(p => p.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query will work if can have initial seed of `OrderBy`. Then you can chain ThenBy's. As mentioned, `ThenBy` requires an `IOrderedEnumerable` (or `IOrderedQueryable`) first before attaching `ThenBy` clauses:

Your code will look like below:

```
IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedQuery = null;
for(int temp = 0; temp < orderBys.Count; temp++)
{
    if(temp == 0)
        orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(orderBys[temp]);

    else orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenBy(orderBys[temp]);  
}
query = orderedQuery ?? query;
```

Reference: [How to generate a dynamic number of ThenBy clauses in a Specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121828/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-number-of-thenby-clauses-in-a-specification)